# unable to login with my details

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, mysqli

I'm creating a login page where users can login in to their account using name and their email id. I'm facing an issue in the login page, when i try to enter the details with proper email id and name its not getting logged in.I'm new to ajax. what should i do to get it to work? please can any one guide me, im trying it from three days but not getting it to be worked

login.php

```
                    <!DOCTYPE HTML>  
                    <html>
                        <head>
                            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
                            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
                            <script src="script.js"></script>
                            <style>
                            .error {
                                color: red;
                                display: none;
                            }



                            .div1 {
                                margin-top: -19px;
                                margin-bottom: -25px;
                                margin-left: -19px; 
                            }

                            .copy {
                                border-radius: 4px;
                                padding: 6px 20px;
                                border-style: ridge;
                            }



                        #error_message{
                        background: #F3A6A6;
                    }

                    .ajax_response {
                        padding: 10px 20px;
                        border: 0;
                        display: inline-block;
                        margin-top: 20px;
                        cursor: pointer;
                        display:none;
                        color:#555;
                    }
                            </style>
                        </head>
                        <body style="background-color:#80bfff">  

                            <div style="padding-left: 380px; padding-top:80px" class="div1">

                                <h2 style="color:#009999">Login :</h2>

                                <p><span class="error">All fields are required </span></p>

                                <form action="" method="post" id="logForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                                    <span style="color:#0099ff">Name: </span>
                                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="copy" style="margin-left: 52px"  value ="" />
                                    <span class="namee error">Enter name</span>
                                    <br/><br/>

                                    <span style="color:#0099ff"> E-mail: </span>
                                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="copy" style="margin-left: 48px"  value ="" />
                                    <span class="emaile error">Enter email</span>
                                    <br/><br/>

                                    <input type="button" id="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="Register" /> 
                                    <p style="color:black">Haven't Registered? <a href="index.php">Register here</a>.</p><br><br>

                                    <div id="error_message" class="ajax_response" style="float:left"></div>

                                </form>

                            </div>

                        </body>

                        <script>
                        $(document).ready(function(){
                            $("#submit").click(function(){
                                var error = false;
                                var form = document.getElementById('logForm');
                                var formData = new FormData(form);

                                // Loop through the form data
                                for(var p of formData){
                                    // Check if the form data is empty
                                    if(p[1] === ''){
                                        // Show the error
                                        $('.'+p[0]+'e').show();
                                        error = true;
                                    }
                                }

                                // prevent AJAX from running in case of an error
                                if(error){
                                    return false;
                                }

                                // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "success.php",
                                    data: formData,
                                    processData: false,
                                    contentType: false,
                                    cache: false,
                                    success: function(data){
                                        if (data['success']==true) {
                                            window.location = 'pannel.php';
                                        }   
                                        else {
                                            alert('Invalid Credentials');
                                        }

                                    }

                                });

                            });
                        });
                        </script>

                    </html>
```

success.php

```
        <?php


                    $mysqli  = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ajax1");

                    $name=$_POST["name"];
                    $email=$_POST["email"];

                    //Checking is user existing in the database or not
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE name='$name' and email='$email'";
                    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
                    $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                    if($rows==1){
                        $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
                        $_SESSION['id']=$row1['userid'];
                            echo "successfully logged in";
                        }
                         else{
                             $error = " Invalid Name or E-MAIL ";
                            }
            ?>
```

pannel.php

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
                <head>

                    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
                    <meta charset="utf-8">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


                </head>
            <body>



                <div class="container">
                    <br><br><br><br>
                    <?php

                        $mysqli  = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ajax1");
                        $query=mysqli_query($mysqli,"select * from `users` where userid='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
                        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
                        echo 'Welcome - '.$row['name'];

                    ?>

                    <br>
                    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
                    <br><br>



                </div>

            </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: You should be using prepared statements, with that code you're vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks

Comment: sir i will fix that but even though i give correct email id and name its still showing invalid cerdentials please what i should do sir

Comment: if you do a var_dump on $_SESSION, what do you get?

Comment: ok sir i will check and tel you

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\3\success.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\3\success.php on line 8

Comment: i'm getting this error sir

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you need to start the session in php like below

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

I hope it will work...

Comment: where i should paste this code sir ? in which file? session.php?

Comment: paste it in success.php and pannel.php

Comment: then check the sql  qurey to check login is working properly or not

Comment: ya sir its correct, can u verify once in my question i have pasted all the files which i have used

Comment: no check your query in ur db then you can debug where is a real issue

Comment: please can u guide me a bit more sir please

Comment: you have problem with ajax call so you can refer [this link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery)